# how to compare two xmi files of two activity diagrams and to display the differences among them?

Tags: c#, xml

I am doing this in C# Visual studio 2008. I did the Xmi  files from AgroUmL by export feature.
kindly please help me....

how to compare two xmi files of  two activity diagrams and to display the differences among them?

with out  use of any other tools, but write the code to compare the two xmi files][1]

Comment: This has nowhere near enough information to give an answer; how are you comparing the files? Is whitespace significant? Case? Namespaces? Does it need to match a schema? How do you "display the differences"? Graphically? As edit commands? XSL?

Comment: the differences are in terms of recall values and precision values for two files.I display these values using a form in visual studio.

Comment: http://www.se-rwth.de/~maoz/papers/diff-ad-fse11.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just compare the XML files, Use [WinDiff](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/159214) which comes with Visual Studio or any other [file comparison tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools)

Comment: Thank you very much . But I need to write code to compare each node by node of two files.

Comment: Why do you accept an answer that doesn't solve your problem?